# Angular 7: Reusing angular resolver service functions

Tags: angular

I have an Angular resolver service, which is called to fetch data before the component is loaded:

```
import {CustomService} from "path/to/custom/service";

@Injectable()
export class ABCResolverService {

  constructor(private customService: CustomService) {
  }

  resolve(): Observable<any> {
    return combineLatest(
      this.fetchA(),
      this.fetchB())
      .pipe(map((data: any) => {
          return data;
      }));
  }

  fetchA(someParams?: string): Observable<any> {
    /*..
      code to develop params to pass
      based on user's profile and other resolver configs
     */
    return this.fetchA(someParams).pipe(map((data: any) => {
        return data;
      }));

  };

  fetchB(): Observable<any> {
    return this.fetchB.pipe(map((data: any) => {
        return data;
      }));
  };

}
```

Inside the component, I want to call fetchA() function again, with changed parameters (like pagination parameters, search text params etc.)

I call the functions inside the component in the following manner:

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-blah',
      templateUrl: './blah.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./blah.component.scss']
});

export class ABCComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _abcResolverService: ABCResolverService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  customSearch(customParams){
    /**
      customParams calculation
    */
    this._abcResolverService.fetchA(customParams)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('enjoy', data);
    });

  }

}
```

But trying to reuse this service function in the component fails with an error

`Cannot read property fetchA of undefined`

I understand this is because the "**this**" keyword becomes undefined when called from an external component, because the scope changes.

What is the best way to call this service function so that the "**this**" keyword has all the properties of ABCResolverService class?

**Workaround**:
The workaround I am using right now is defining the fetchA, fetchB methods again in the component, but that just feels like redundant code.

Comment: Have you tried using instance arrow function like `customSearch = customParams => {`?

Comment: @yurzui No I didn't. Can you please guide me to the docs or reference for such usage? Or may be elaborate a little?

Comment: @yurzui Hey actually that worked! Is it because of the arrow functions that the current context (this) doesn't leave the function at all even other functions are called inside it?